# Perché si dice "dormire saporitamente"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, adverbs

Nel racconto *Riccardo e la sirena* di Marisa Madieri ho letto:

> "Con maglione, berretto e merenda, Riccardo prese il largo con papà Matteo e zio Nando, in un'ora in cui di solito già *dormiva saporitamente*."

Ho trovato che il [significato di *saporitamente*](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/saporitamente) in questo contesto è:

> Con placida e beata soddisfazione.

L'avverbio *saporitamente* però proviene di "sapore" e, per questa ragione, mi chiedo e vi chiedo: qual è l'origine di questo uso del vocabolo "saporitamente"?

Comment: In attesa di ripose più circostanziate, ipotizzo che l'uso di questo avverbio per riferirlo al sonno sia nato in origine per dare l'idea che uno “assapora” il sonno, se lo gode pienamente; dopodiché è diventata una frase fatta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deriva dall'uso dell'avverbio [saporitamente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/saporito/) in senso figurato. L'idea è quella che un buon sonno possa essere 'gustato' come un buon cibo.

> - ◆ Avv. saporitaménte, in modo saporito: una vivanda saporitamente condita; di gusto, con vivo piacere, beatamente: cominciava a ber sì saporitamente questo suo vino, che egli n’avrebbe fatto venir voglia a’ morti (Boccaccio); **per estens., molto com., dormire saporitamente.**     (Treccani online)

Secondo [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dormire%20saporitamente&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdormire%20saporitamente%3B%2Cc0) l'espressione viene usata da circa dalla metà del XIX secolo.